# Global variable for all threads in CUDA

Tags: cuda, boolean, global-variables

I need global bool variable in my console application , so how to declare it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to declare a variable that would reside in CUDA global memory you need to put `__device__` keyword in front of it, e.g.

```
__device__ bool myGlobalBoolVar;
```

Alternatively, you can allocate memory in global memory space with `cudaMalloc`, e.g.

```
bool* myGlobalBoolVarPtr;
cudaMalloc(&myGlobalBoolVarPtr, sizeof(bool));
```

then you can pass the pointer as a parameter to the kernel. Note, the pointer parameter itself will reside either in constant or shared memory space (depending on the architecture) but it will point to global memory.